# How to use Makefile in docker-machine

Tags: makefile, docker

like Window or OSX, docker-machine is used start linux env, but make is not installed.
I have a Makefile to pull/build/start docker, could not run. how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boot2docker VM is based on [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/welcome.html), to install a package use `tce-load`:

```
docker-machine ssh <profile>
tce-load -wi make
```

To search for packages you can use the interactive `tce` tool.

Comment: When I run `$ tce-load -wi make` I get `make is already downloaded.` I cannot seem to install `make`. `/usr/local/bin/make` does not exist.